Is there a way to call a kusto function when connected to a different cluster from the one where the function resides?
When running queries on Kusto tables, one  can prefix the table as follows:
Cluster("cluster name").Database("db name").table'

Is there a similar approach for functions?

Cluster("cluster name").Database("db name").FunctionName() i think this is possible right ? Cluster("cluster name").Database("db name").FunctionName(param1, param2) ??


Is there a way to call a Kusto function when connected to a different cluster from the one where the function resides?

Yes, you can call Kusto function which is present in another cluster. Try with the below code, it successfully connects with the other cluster and retrieves data stored from the other cluster.
Below is the function GetStaticData() stored in clusterpb03.

Below is the other cluster clusterpb04 where no data has stored in it.

Try with the below code to retrieve data from clusterpb03.
cluster('https://clusterpb03.eastus.kusto.windows.net').database('db1').GetStaticData
|  project  CustomerId,  CustomerName,  Region

Output:

For more information, please refer to this link by @Sander van de Velde.
